# What tense should we use in the present time (now) to refer to an event happening during a future other event?

Tags: future-tense

I have planned a meeting, that will be the day after tomorrow.

If now I want to tell someone about the main point of the meeting, what could I choose?

> - During the meeting **we are discussing** about XYZ
> - During the meeting **we are going to discuss** about XYZ
> - During the meeting **we'll** discuss about XYZ
> - During the meeting **we discuss** about XYZ
> - Something else...

Thank you.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd sound correct, 4rd is correct if the meeting is a general one not any specific meeting. Dont use about with discuss, we discuss a particular issue but we talk about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meeting will be in the future.  Therefore, it is appropriate to use a form that indicates the future.  (As pointed out by Barrie England in a note, English has no future tense.)  Some possibilities are:

> - During the meeting we will discuss XYZ.
> - During the meeting we'll discuss XYZ.
> - During the meeting we'll be discussing XYZ.
> - During the meeting we are going to discuss XYZ.

"about" isn't necessary with discuss; it would be appropriate with "talk about", but "discuss" is a better choice for this situation.

Comment: As FumbleFingers has said on EL&U, English has no future tense: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110287/improper-expressions-of-the-future-progressive

Answer (score 2):

*To discuss* something means the same thing as *to talk about* something, so the word 'about' is not correct to use with 'discuss'.  So, to go through your examples (removing 'about'):

> - During the meeting we are discussing XYZ.

Incorrect. The meeting is in the future, and "we are discussing" is present tense. You can't use the two together.

> - During the meeting we are going to discuss XYZ.

Correct.  "We are going to" talks about the future, and so is appropriate here.

> - During the meeting we'll discuss XYZ.

Correct. *We'll* is a contraction of *we will*, which is also future tense and appropriate here.

> - During the meeting we discuss XYZ.

Incorrect.  *We discuss [x]* refers to a habit in this case. If you have a recurring meeting in which you always discuss the same thing, you could instead say:

> - During the [weekly, daily, etc.] meetings we discuss XYZ.

Answer (score 0):

As @WendiKidd says, I wouldn't use 'about' with discuss. Either **discuss** or **talk about**.

Other than that, I think all the sentences are correct, but "During the meeting we'll discuss XYZ" sounds the most ordinary.